# Misbehaving margins

Tags: css, html

Or maybe it's the height acting up. Anyway, I have a list composed of divs inside a containing div, and I'm using margins to position them vertically they way I'd like. Everything works fine, except for the last item in the list. The bottom extends all the way to the bottom of the container. I've tried various padding and margin fixes, and several of the results have been even further off of the intent (the goal is basically to have the bottom symmetrical to the top, with a gap between the last item and the bottom of the container).

An example, including all of the relevant CSS and HTML, is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BcEKJ/).

The target browser is Internet Explorer 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on @Niko 's answer

This means you'll have the equivalent of:

```
margin-top:6%;
margin-bottom:6%;
```

On each .ListItem. 'Margin collapsing' ensures that when margins are touching each other the smaller one is 'collapsed' or effectively removed. This means you will not have doubled up margins on the boxes.

Additionally, you could insert `&nbsp;` before the closing tag of the containing div. This will insert a non-breaking space below the last list item.

Comment: I get the same result with that. Everything is still positioned correctly, but what should be grey space between the last list item and the bottom of the container is white.

Comment: Sounds like a possible ie bug? You can add 
   
    &nbsp;


Just before the closing </div> of #ListContainer

Comment: Non-breaking space, just an empty character. I think it works because IE8 requires some content for the margin to work. I don't really know! Wish I could be of more help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `margin: 6% 0;` on `.ListItem` to resolve that problem (adds extra margin to the bottom).

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/BcEKJ/1/

I added simple `padding-bottom: 6%;` to `#ListContainer`.

Comment: I've tried that and it didn't work (your sample doesn't either). Maybe this is browser-specific? Which browser are you using, and did this actually fix it for you?

Comment: It should work in any browser. Firefox, opera, chrome, IE. This is such basic thing. What about this http://jsfiddle.net/BcEKJ/6/

Comment: Are you sure both scrollers are down to the bottom?

Comment: Yes, both scrollers are down to the bottom, and yes, that gives the same result.

Comment: IE8 (it's mentioned in the question)

Comment: If you add this extra padding to the ListContainer, you need to reduce its height to 94% to still have a total height of 100%.

Comment: Or change box model. (CSS box sizing)